MASSIVE memory spikes in React Native when images are rendered in a list
I am going to post a description of the problem we face and steps we tried to take it to address it, as well as screenshots from profiler.
For some context, we are small startup where we have a list of snaps/moments displayed in chronological order in 2 columns. Naturally, a user can view hundreds of such images as they scroll. The issue is that our memory spikes a lot, and we can't figure out how to control it.
We use the library here as we found it to be better than its alternatives for following reasons:

Image from React Native: Terrible on Android and doesn't load the images at all
react-native-fast-image: Library is not maintained at all
react-native-turbo-image: Sluggish on Android as we have to disable hardware bitmaps. If we don't, then it crashes due to react-navigation

We face the spikes with all libraries, except for Image but that's because this library doesn't load the images in the first places.
For rendering, we use Flatlist and have utilized all props, but for now the following props are being used to control memory:

initialNumToRender = 4
removeClippedSubviews = true
maxToRenderPerBatch = 4
windowSize = 4

We used the onEndReached prop to trigger a fetch for next posts. This fetch consists of making firebase calls and updating the list that we pass in the data field for flatlist. Inside each item, images are fetched with CDNs and we have verified that all images are < 5MB and ~95% are <= 1MB.
Flashlist doesn't help with memory and also the images flicker a lot when scrolled fast, and that is unacceptable.
We have tried clearing the cache of FasterImage with clearCache, and have tried calling the GC manually but neither approach works.
The app initially starts off with ~500-600MB on Android, and rises up to 2GB when scrolled fast enough. Capturing the heap dump reveals that majority of the Native Memory is occupied by Bitmap (android.graphics). I have attached a screenshot of the same.


Is there a way to reduce the memory footprint by manually calling some function? Has anyone faced this issue in React Native? Any help would be appreciated. Also, we face this in iOS too but I am the Android dev and don't have the logs for iOS. For iPhones, the maximum spike is ~850MB.
Our flatlist code looks like this:
import { FasterImageView } from '@candlefinance/faster-image'

<FlatList
  onEndReached={() => fetch(true)}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
  ref={scrollRef}
  style={{ flex: 1, overflow: 'hidden' }}
  initialNumToRender={4}
  windowSize={4}
  maxToRenderPerBatch={4}
  removeClippedSubviews={true}
  data={Object.keys(postsKey)}
  keyExtractor={item => item}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <View key={index} style={{ overflow: 'hidden', marginTop: 20 }}>
      <Text style={{ ...getFontFamily('Montserrat', 600), fontSize: 17, lineHeight: 18, color: '#000', marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 15 }}>{item}</Text>
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={false}
        initialNumToRender={4}
        windowSize={4}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={4}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        data={postsKey[item]}
        renderItem={({ item, i }) => <PostCard key={i} post={item} index={i} posts={allPosts} setDisplayIndex={setDisplayIndex} userStreaks={userStreaks} userProfilePictures={userProfilePictures} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        numColumns={2}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  )}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={() => fetch(false)} tintColor={DEFAULT_COLOR} />
  }
/>


have you read Optimizing Flatlist Configuration?

Use Kotlin for performance and React for money saving

You are probably using a development build. This always has a large runtime. Therefore, it would be better to make a preview build and to the same exercise again. Your runtime performance will drop.

@Thomasino73 we are facing this issue in the release build too, in fact on the versions that are currently live.

@GauravBharadia It's a bit too late for that. We are a team of 4 engineers and app is already in an advanced stage. I wish development was separate for iOS and Android, but I joined after a big portion of the app was made in React Native

@flix Yes, I have read the configuration and tried the suggestions in it. We still face the issues

if so, the main issue should be how you implement it, you should check how the screen rendering, I usually use RND and profiling to check how many render appear when I navigate to suspected screen

@flix RND doesnt work due to usage of react-native-quick-crypto. It throws an Invariant Violation error. I had tried fixing it a month back but to no avail. I'll see if there is any way to figure out re-rendering issue, but I don't get why so many bitmaps are created and not flushed out of memory as seen in the profiler

@Mohammad Anas I'm not sure what this list should look like, but isn't it possible to flatten your data, so you don't need to use a Flatlist nested inside another flatlist like https://snack.expo.dev/@ronicesarrc/17ef66? Have you considered using SectionList https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist?

@RoniCastro Yes that is what I did yesterday. Took a long time but that has brought RAM usage within 350MB on iOS and 1.3GB Android. Thanks for the suggestion.

My assumption is that it seems to be some closure problem, which is keeping a reference to each item on your list, and if that happens, basically, no item on your list will ever be recycled and will be kept in memory. Without an example code to reproduce the problem, it is difficult to help you

I'd try to break the problem into a smaller one, like removing some components, removing some props, and trying just rendering the images to see if the problem is really the images or something else.

@RoniCastro changing it to a single flatlist has fixed the issue. I agree with your assumption of items not being recycled. In an earlier solution to confirm this I had kept a window of 30 posts using viewability config while other components out of the window in inner flatlist were set to return <></>. This had reduced the native memory usage too as the Bitmap memory went down significantly.

Btw there is an actively maintained fork for react-native-fast-image: https://github.com/dream-sports-labs/react-native-fast-image

I had this problem with rendering multiple charts in a flatlist.
Shopify solved the problem with this alternative that replaces react-svg with skia. Skia is a much more efficient rendering engine.
Since you have a flatlist inside a flatlist I'd suggest giving it ago.
https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/
it's also possible you're just using a development build and heavy renders don't perform well outside of the optimizations applied in a production build.

Flashlist helped me optimize my lists by over 30% in both speed and memory optimizations.

I tried Flashlist and it doesn't work with numColumns = 2. Maybe in future I can look into rendering rows instead of an image in renderItem.
Also, in my earlier use of Flashlist it flickered when scrolled extremely fast and when data passed to it changed, which happens frequently in our use case as we fetch X at a time.
I have changed my data to a single flatlist and that has helped significantly.
Here is the link for Flashlist issue with numColumns: https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list/issues/797#issuecomment-2033226370

ah for more configuration options take look at https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/guides/masonry/

for the flickering the trick is the same as flatlist, you've gotta tweak the numRenderedItems etc values until it performs

I fixed the problem but I really like your suggestion, it's the only useful one I have got. I will look into migrating my new code to masonry flash list later on.
